# How to test transactional work performed on `POST_COMMIT_INSERT` callback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, transactions

I'm having difficulty debugging and diagnosing an issue within my application.

I have a JPA event listener wired in to perform work in a `POST_COMMIT_INSERT`.  The work that is performed is also transactional.

I'm having difficulty writing a test that captures the work that occurred in the post-transactional transaction.

My current test performs it's assertions in a `@PostTransaction` method.  However, although I see the data being persisted (using log statements), the postTransaction-transaction work isn't available to me.

I suspect it's because in my `@PostTransaction` method, I'm still too early - and that there's another transaction in progress.

Here's a sample that roughly demonstrates the scenario:

> After a `Foo` has been created & saved, create and save a `Bar`.

```
// Step 1.  The factory that responds to creation of the Foo, and build a bar.
@Component
class BarFactory implements PostInsertEventListener
{
     // Note:  I've tried various versions of @Transactional on different points
     // within this class, and none have worked.

     @Autowired
     private BarRepository repository;

     @Override
     public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) 
     {
         if (event.getEntity() instanceof Foo)
         {
             createBar();
         }
     }
     @Transactional
     public createBar()
     {
         Bar bar = new Bar();
         repository.save(bar);
         log.info("Bar was created: " + bar.getId());
     }
 }

 // Step 2:  Register the BarFactory
 @Component
 class LifecycleListenerFactory {
    // This is a spring bean, and the listeners are also spring beans
    // so we have to use a somewhat long-winded approach to register them
    // with the EntityManager
    @Autowired
    public LifecycleListenerFactory(EntityManager em, BarFactory barFactory)
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory(em);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        EventListenerGroup<PostInsertEventListener> eventListenerGroup = registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT);
        eventListenerGroup.appendListener(barFactory);
    }


   SessionFactory getSessionFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
       Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
       SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
       return sessionFactory;
   }
 } 


// Step 3:  Test.
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
class MyTest {
   @Autowired
   private FooRepository fooRepo;
   @Autowired
   private BarRepository barRepo;

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
       fooRepo.save(new Foo());
   }

   @AfterTransaction
   public void assert()
   {
       assertThat(barRepo.findAll().size(),equalTo(1));
   }
}
```

In this scenario, I see the following output:

`INFO:  Bar was created: 1`

But the test fails.

Am I correct in my assumption that my `@AfterTransaction` is running after the wrong transaction, or is something else wrong here?

If so, how do I test this?

I've tried moving the `@Transaction` boundaries around in the `BarFactory`, but that hasn't had any effect.